# What is the difference between $e^{it}$ and $e^{st}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm currently trying to make sense of the Laplace transform, but I'm a bit stumped by the $e^{-st}$ part of the transform.

I understand Euler's formula $e^{it} = \cos(t)+i\sin(t)$, but I don't understand why in the Laplace transform it is a whole complex number in the exponent?

I assume $e^{st}$ is not equal to $\cos(t) + i\sin(t)$.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In this context, the imaginary unit is a constant, $i = \sqrt{-1}$, and $s$ is a variable.

Comment: Are you familiar with Fourier transforms?

Comment: @Moo The notation $\sqrt {-1}$ is ambiguous since any non-zero complex number has two square roots.

Comment: @Gary, that may be so, but this is generally accepted in this context: https://mathvault.ca/euler-formula/

Comment: $s$ is a variable; the result of the Laplace transform is a function of $s$.

Comment: With $s= a+ib$ then $e^{st} = e^{at} e^{i bt}$ is a damped complex exponential, $e^{at}$ is the damping factor and $b$ is the speed at which the complex exponential rotates around the real axis. It looks like this https://www.mdpi.com/geotechnics/geotechnics-01-00016/article_deploy/html/images/geotechnics-01-00016-g013.png (the red spiral)

Answer (score 4):

Laplace transform $F$ of a function $f$ is given by the formula $$F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\,dt. \tag{1}$$
First, let's discuss what $t$ is. It's a dummy variable used for integration, it takes value in $[0,\infty)$. It often represents time in applications.
Note that $t$ would disappear in a closed-formula for $F$ after integration takes place, but $s$ will remain and therefore the above integral defines a function in variable $s$ (when it converges). So, $s$ is a complex variable, not a fixed number.

The imaginary unit $i$, on the other hand, is a fixed complex number, so comparing $s$ and $i$ in this context is like apples and oranges. For example, if we used $it$ instead of $-st$, if integral $$\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{it}\,dt\tag{2}$$ converges, the result is just another complex number, not a function of a complex variable. *(Well, technically, any constant can be interpreted as a function, but that wouldn't be interesting here.)*

So, to recapitulate, the expression $e^{-st}$ in this context has two parameters, $s$ a complex one, and $t$ non-negative real, so $(s,t)\mapsto e^{-st}$ is a function with domain $\mathbb C\times [0,\infty)$. The expression $e^{it}$ has only one parameter $t$, while $i$ is a constant, so $t\mapsto e^{it}$ is a function with domain $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: +1 Perhaps worth noting that if you replace $st$ by $2\pi ist$ you have the Fourier transform.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how would you evaluate e^-st as it is alone without the integral? Let's say you just picked t = 1 and s = (1+i1)?

If I were trying to evaluate e^it for t = 2pi  I could just say cos(2pi)+i*sin(2 pi) and that would yield a complex number: 1+i*0. ( I know there is no imaginary part here because sin(2 pi) = 0 but a lot of other t-values would yield an imaginary part.

Comment: You don't pick $t$ since it's variable used for integration. You pick $s$ instead, let's say $s = 1+2i$. Then you evaluate integral $\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-(1+2i)t}\,dt$. If it converges, that's the value of $F(1+2i)$. @JanF.S

Comment: That's how it works in principle, but in practice you don't do it for concrete $s$. For example, if $f(t) = 1$ for $t\geq 0$, we have $F(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}\,dt =\left. -e^{-st}/s \right|_0^\infty = \lim_{t\to\infty}(-e^{-st}/s)-(-1/s).$ The limit exists for $\operatorname{Re}s > 0$ and for those $s$ we have $F(s) = 1/s$. @JanF.S

Comment: I don't quite follow when you say T is just a dummy variable.
if you are taking a definite integral with respect to t then by definition you must be multiplying the values for the integrand with their associated T-values throughout from your bottom limit to your top limit. I'm not sure how that works with infinity as an upperl imit.

Comment: Btw I'm not trying to be intentionally dense or anything, but a professional mathematician once advised me to always do specific examples when trying to see patterns and that's what i'm trying to do here when I want to evaluate specific examples of e^-st

Comment: @JanF.S it's a dummy variable in a sense that it will disappear after integration. In my previous comment you can see a worked out example, don't really know what to add other than that. You can easily find more examples here on MSE or just google it, which I advise you to do. Whenever you struggle with a definition or a concept, just take a look at examples, and return to formal stuff later.

Answer (score 2):

This is my opinion. The Laplace transform is usually used to convert a linear ODE to an algebraic equation to make it easier to find a solution. The transformation given by
$$
F(s) = \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}
$$
has a polynomial common denominator. (The notation $F(s)$ shows that we are taking $s$ as a variable but not a constant.) For example,
$$
F(s) = \frac{\cdots}{(s-a) \cdots (s^2 + bs+ c) \cdots}
$$
where the order of the polynomial is not larger than the order of the ODE. From this transformation, someone observed that the roots of the polynomial have important information about the solution to the linear ODE. The roots are generally complex numbers as you might know. For that reason, it is natural to set $s = \sigma + i\omega$ as a complex number.